# Deploying website with msdeploy(webdeploy)

Tags: asp.net, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm using webdeploy to publish my website following a build server in tfs2010.

I've excluded the web.config from the package as I want to keep the one on the destination server.

The problem is that since the web.config is not part of the package, webdeploy deletes the web.config file from the destination server !

how can I prevent that ? I haven't found in options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include that in your package.

Comment: include what ? You mean the web.config file that is already on the server ? If so, I can't do that as I don't want anyone to have even read access to this file. It needs to stay on the server and never be touched or redeployed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out... I needed to add this extra parameter to msdeploy.exe :

-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule